# SQL generate a random positive or negative value

Tags: mysql, random

I am looking for a way to change a value randomly from positive to negative. (I am creating a distortion on a lat/long location, so I would like to offset a given location with +/- some degrees)

I already created the following query which give me a number between -1 and +1, the idea is to multiply my distortion with this number to get a random negative or positive number.

```
SELECT round(-1+3*RAND(),0);
```

The only problem is, this also generates the value 0.0 which can't be multiplied. How do I get -1 or +1 only?

TIA

ABBOV

Comment: MySQL is really not very good at dealing with PRNG randomisations; at scale you would be much more efficient to give the data to your interface language (PHP or whatever) and let that do the data manipulation.

Comment: 0.0 can be multiplied just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

1. start by rounding, to give `0` or `1`
2. then multiply to give `0` or `2`
3. then subtract, to give `-1` or `1`

i.e.:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(RAND()) * 2 - 1;
```